# Can I create and restore partial backups with mariabackup on MariaDB 10.1.23?

Tags: backup, mariadb

I read in Percona xtrabackup manual that xtrabackup require MySQL 5.6 for restoring partial backups (only some databases or tables). But there are nothing about MariaDB. How about mariabackup? I have MariaDB 10.1.23. Does mariabackup support partial backup and restoring for this version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you do it exactly in the same way, like you would do in Percona, substituting xtrabackup with mariabackup (or innobackupex with "mariabackup --innobackupex" on the command line)

Comment: With this specific version? 10.1.23?

Comment: I found that mariabackup support --export option only for versions since 10.2.29. But it requires for restoring

Comment: And Percona XtraBackup support partial restoring for Mysql since 5.6. But nothing found about MariaDB

Comment: mariabackup ---export works in 10.1, since it was checked in to 10.1 . I do not track the tiny version, but if there is mariabackup in 10.1,it does do export. You also can try and see

Answer (score 1):

You can use Percona Xtrabackup / innobackupex to do partial backups of MariaDB databases (as long as you haven't used compression or at-rest encryption). I've personally used this with MariaDB version 10.1. (**Note**: From MariaDB 10.3 onwards, xtrabackup no longer works properly.)

MariaDB Backup (`mariabackup`) is a fork of Percona Xtrabackup (with added support for compression and at-rest encryption), so (logically) this should therefore also support partial backups. MariaDB 10.1.23 is the version where MariaDB Backup was first introduced. Since this is an alpha release of the tool, it's not recommended for use in a production environment. See this [MariaDB blog post](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-backup-released-mariadb-server-10123) for details.

It would seem that partial backups are supported at least in later versions, as `mariabackup` has options to specify particular databases and tables to back up as well as tables and databases to exclude from backup.